# Change btrfs compression level

Tags: btrfs

I have created a btrfs filesystem with compression, using the compress option in fstab and it seems to be working. I would quite like to try the higher level of compression. I can change this in fstab, but if I understand it this will affect only new files. I can also recompress with `btrfs filesystem defragment`. This allows me to set the algorithm but I can't see how to change the level.

Is there a way to achieve this? I was going to try zlib level 9.

Comment: why not try ZStd ?

Comment: I don't know who to

Answer (score 1):

From `btrfs-progs` version 4.15 you can recompress with another compression level for zlib like this:

```
btrfs fi defrag -czlib:9 ...
```

For zstd compression level is supported from version 5.1.

See https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog

But be careful with defrag as it will unreference the snapshot structure of the btrfs filesystem, which might lead to a substantial increase in disk usage.

Comment: defrag does [not support compression levels](https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/issues/184), so the suggested command will not work.